# Python Blackjack Functions and Inputs Arrangement

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

This code should to generate a blackjack hand, keep score, and tally the number of soft aces. It should stop or proceed depending on the type of game. The code isn't arranged properly and keeps the "total" value and/or "hand" empty giving an infinite while loop. How do I arrange the code so it returns the desired outcome?

```
import random

def get_card():
    #hand = []
    card = random.randint(1, 13)
    if card == 10 or card == 11 or card == 12 or card == 13:
        card = 10
    #hand.append(card)
    #return hand
    return card

def score():
    """
    keeps score of the hand and counts saft aces.
    """
    hand = []
    card = get_card()
    #hand = [get_card()]
    game_type = input("Enter 'soft'for S17 ot 'hard for H17'.")
    total = 0
    soft_ace_count = 0
    for ele in range(0, len(hand)):
        total = total + hand[ele]

    while len(hand) <= 5:
        while total <= 17 and game_type == 'soft':
            if card == 1:
                card = 11
                hand.append(card)

        while total <= 17 and game_type == 'hard':
            if card == 1:
                hand.append(card)

        if ele in hand == 11:
                soft_ace_count += 1

    return(total, soft_ace_count)
```

I also want to modularize the program and compute the probability of busting based on a number of user-defined simulations. I don't know how to set up the simulations for-loop to temporarily save the simulations results for calculation the probability. Should I place them in a temporary file?

````
def main():
    try:
        num_simulations = int(input("Please enter the desired number of simulations: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an integer value for the nummer of simulations.")

    try:
        stand_on_value = int(input("Please enter a score value to stand on. "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an integer value for the stand-on score.")

    try:
        game_type = input("Enter 'soft' for S17 or 'hard' for H17.")
    except ValueError:
        if game_type != 'soft' or game_type != 'hard':
            print("Please enter 'soft' or 'hard'.")

    for i in range(0, num_simulations):
        get_card()
        score()

    "for-loop to calculate probability of busting as the percentage of busted hands in the simulations."```
````

Comment: I think you can do better in the question you ask the user....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `while` loop will continue for ever since you never adapt `total`, but there are several other issues:

- when the `if` condition within the `while` is false then also the hand is not extended and nothing else happens.
- Whenever the loop iterates, you should select a new card
- The `for ele in range(0, len(hand))` is useless where it is currently placed, as there is no card in the hand
- `if ele in hand == 11` is not doing what you want. It should be `if 11 in hand`. Even better is to just do this job when you actually set the card to 11. Then no more additional `if` is needed.
- As only one `while` loop condition of the two loops can ever be true, use only one `while` loop and make the distinction within it.

Change to this:

```
def score():
    game_type = input("Enter 'soft' for S17 or 'hard' for H17.")
    hand = []
    total = 0
    soft_ace_count = 0
    while total <= 17:
        card = get_card()
        total += card # you must bring total up to date here
        if game_type == 'soft' and card == 1 and total <= 11:
            card = 11
            total += 10  # adapt to the new value of the card
            soft_ace_count += 1  # move this here...
        # so you can see what is happening 
        print("Got card {}. Total is {}".format(card, total))  
        hand.append(card) # always append...
    # Do you plan to do something with hand? Do you really need it?
    # ...
    return total, soft_ace_count  # parentheses are not needed
```

I did not verify the rest of your code, but this at least solves the matter of your question.

Comment: Thanks! This is getting it on track. I need to make the soft game stand on 17. How do I achieve that? I was thinking adding another condition to the if statement: `if game_type == 'soft' and card == 1 and total <=17`

Comment: That would make sense if you moved the line with `total += card` before the `if`. But then inside the `if` block you must add another 10 to the `total`. I have updated the code in my answer like that just now.

Comment: I do wonder why you would accept `total` to be (for instance) 16 to go into the `if` block, because then you're busted. Should it not be `total <= 11`?

Comment: Yes it should. I tried that and it simulates the stand on 17. Thanks!

Comment: You should not add another question. If you really cannot make that idea of simulation work, you should post a new question dedicated to that issue.

Comment: I will do that. Thank you!